# W8BEN form Tax Treaty details for an Indian student receiving a (Travel) Award from a US-based organization

Tags: united-states, india, form-w-8-ben, student

I'm a Indian student living in India. I have been selected for a Travel Award for attending a conference in a country that is neither US nor India. However, the conference organization is US-based and has asked me to fill the W8BEN form for further processing on their end.

I can find the Ww8ben form at https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw8ben.pdf.

And the tax-treaty document at
https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-trty/india.pdf.

I gather that the relevant information is in Article 21; so I want to confirm  if this is the appropriate information to fill for point 10:

> Special rates and conditions (if applicable—see instructions): The beneficial owner is claiming the provisions of Article and paragraph **Article 21 Paragraph I and II** of the treaty identified on line 9 above to claim a **0** % rate of withholding on (specify type of income): **Travel Award**.
>
> Explain the additional conditions in the Article and paragraph the beneficial owner meets to be eligible for the rate of withholding: **a student or business apprentice described in paragraph 1 - A student or business apprentice who is or was a resident of one of the Contracting States immediately before visiting the other Contracting State**

The withholding rate is 0% because this income qualifies for exemption (?).

I also want to confirm that if these fields are left blank (a friend has done so), the default withholding rate of 30ish% will be applicable (?), since awards are taxable in USA.

Comment: If you are not a US resident and the conference is not in the US, why would the award be taxable in the US? If it's not taxable in the US, then there's no point using a tax treaty. The tax treaty provision you cited doesn't apply anyway since it's for people visiting the other state, and you are not visiting the US.

Comment: I thought it might be applicable because I will be receiving the amount through a wire transfer from a US based organization. So, should the fields be left blank then?